# Scrolling div in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add scrolling to the second part, it is "chat-messages" div in "chat-bar" div. I want JUST this "chat-messages" to make scrollable, leaving rest of the site with no any scrool. At this moment I have to scroll the whole site to see "input-row" div. It's quite working when i set `overflow: auto` to the "chat-bar" but then whole `input-row` is also included in scrolling. Please give me best css/html option how to resolve this problem, or give me simple javascript library.

jsfiddle link:

```
jsfiddle.net/o9vmfgpx/3
```

edit:
I made it working, but in some hacky way.

```
.chat-messages {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.chat-messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .chat-messages {
        right: -5%;
        padding-right: 3%;
    }
}
```

Works on latest version of IE, EDGE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera (as 10.14.2016)

Comment: This should be possible with basic CSS. e.g. `.chat-messages{overflow-y: scroll; height: 300px;}`

Comment: Have you found already a solution?

Comment: @K.Daniek yes, but there is no one solution for one browser. I have updated my question with solutions I have found.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
body {
      overflow:hidden;
}
.chat-messages {
       overflow:scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it on js fiddle but its not working there. I know this is it and it should work.

Comment: This make the whole site "static", adds scroolbar to the chat-messages and that's all, I can't scrool chat-messages

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.input-row {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below css?

```
.chat-messages {
  height:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: But what about different resolutions? I want height to be 100% of visible site.

Comment: what about changing to height to 100vh?